# What is the meaning of printf("%p", int 1)?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand the difference between `int a` and `int *a`, my first step was to see the value I could get by printi `%p` of an `int a`. Of course the compiler shows warnings, but does complete the job for the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("a - declared");
    printf("int a = [%d]\n", a);            // example - 1745899614
    printf("int a pointer = [%p]\n", a);    // example - 0x6810505e

    a = 10;
    printf("a - initialized to value of 10\n");
    printf("int a = [%d]\n", a);            // exmaple - 10
    printf("int a pointer = [%p]\n", a);    // example - 0xa

    return 0;
}
```

And as I've mentioned in the source code, I do get a somewhat satisfactory result of `0xa` which is equal to `10` in hexadecimal for the value of `%p` of an `int a`. But is it actually the case that `int` points to to that address, or is this just the compiler trying to make sense of `%p` in such a case?

Where is the memory allocated for `int`s? How do I test for that?

Comment: It means you typed your program wrong. It should be `printf("int a pointer = [%p]\n", &a);` Note the ampersand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print the address of an object named `a`, use:

```
printf("The address of a is %p.\n", (void *) &a);
```

Merely using `%p` does not tell `printf` to print the address of the object you use as the argument. You must use the “address of” operator, `&`, to take the address. Otherwise, you are passing the value of `a` to `printf`, not the address of `a`.

Additionally, it is proper to convert the address to `void *`, as shown above, because the `%p` specifier expects a pointer to `void`. Other types of pointers often work (or appear to work) in many C implementations, but the technical requirement is that a pointer to `void` be passed.

Comment: `const void *` is not compatible with `void *`. C99 6.7.3:9 says “For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the specified type”. Qualifier fuzziness is sometimes explicitly allowed (e.g. in the second item in 6.5:7) but if you have reason to think that it is allowed by C99 to pass a `const void *` for `%p`, I would be very interested in your reasoning. I have been trying to answer this very question recently and it was not clear to me.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Errant text removed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks indeed! The best answer+comment combo on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the formater ( in printf ), is just interpreting the memory as it is told to.  So yeah, "%p" is for pointer, but you gave it an int.  You wanted to give it the address of a:

```
printf( "%p", &a );
```

for the whole shabang:

```
int  a = 10;
int *b = &a;

printf("value of    a: %d\n", a  );
printf("location of a: %p\n", &a );
printf("value of    b: %p\n", b  );
printf("location of b: %p\n", &b );
printf("dereference b: %d\n", *b );
```

Answer (score 1):

> But is it actually the case that int points to to that address, or is
>   this just the compiler trying to make sense of %p in such a case?

It's the latter. Compiler tries to interpret the integer as a pointer. When you print the *value* of `a` using `%p` compiler finds that the type of `a` is `int` and warns you that it's not a pointer.

To print the address of `a` use:

```
printf("int a pointer = [%p]\n", (void*)&a);
```

If `a` is a pointer (e..g `int *a;`) then you need to initialize it with a valid address and then you can print:

```
printf("int a pointer = [%p]\n", (void*)a);
```

Comment: Consider myself enlightened :)

Answer (score 1):

`%p` is merely a way to tell `printf` to print your value as an address memory. You're passing the value of `10`to it (the value of `a`) and you get printed this value in the hexadecimal notation `0xa`. There is no special interpretation, it is just a formatting option.

If you want the value of the `a`'s address memory printed you can simply do `printf("%p", &a);`. `&a` is the address of `a`.

Or if you want to use a pointer:

```
int* p;
p = &a;
printf("%p", p); //Prints the p value, that is the a address. Equivalent to printf("%p", &a).
```